# Multi-threaded C# application log file locking issue

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a bi-threaded c# application where both threads write to the same log and I'm getting an error.

```
'The process cannot access the file 'logfile.log' because it is being used by another process.'
```

I'm somewhat new to C# and multi-threading in general so if anyone can point me in the right direction here it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post more of your code if you want specific help.  The general answer however is to either use a Mutex or synclock on an object before writing.

Comment: Logging isn't as easy as it seems, and multi-threading is always harder than it seems. Use a free library, like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Comment: What's your logging engine? Is it handmade? In that case do not try concurrent access: make a thread-safe Logger with a queue and a secondary background thread for writing (to make it asynchronous). In general when it's about I/O...use "delay and retry" pattern, someday something will happen and you'll need it, for sure.

Comment: @tnw Thank you for that direction, that's what I was looking for

Comment: You will need to post some code for more specific help, but what you really need to do is to lock the file before trying to write to it. Look into mutex's as a place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says that the file is held open by another **process**, not thread. Are you sure the file is being closed properly each time you run your app ?

Generally speaking, you should use a lock to control access to a shared resource inside your application. For example, if you have a LogWriter class with a Log() function, a minimal implementation with no queuing might look like this:

```
public class LogWriter
{
private readonly object _lock = new object;

public void Log(string message)
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        //write message to log file
        string appName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + appName + ".log", true);
        sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:u} {1}", DateTime.Now, message));
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

The `lock(_lock)` ensures that only one thread accesses the file at a time. The `sw.Close()` ensures that the file is not left open when the process terminates ;-)

Comment: The wording "another process" is generic. You get that whether the file is locked by a thread in a separate process, or if it's locked by a thread in your process. In addition, the file system will automatically close files when your process exits, if you don't explicitly close them. It won't flush the buffer, but it *will* close the file.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states, you can't create a writer from multiple different threads.  You'll need to find some way of either synchronizing the access to the file between threads, which is to say ensuring that one thread waits to try to access the file until all other threads are done with it, or you could designate a single thread as being *the* thread responsible for accessing that file, requiring all other threads that want to access that file to request the other thread to do it for them.

Comment: Unfortunately they both need to be able to write to the log

Comment: @BadKarma Not necessarily.  For example, they could each add items to a thread safe in memory queue, which a single thread consumes, writing out the content to a file.  Just because multiple threads need to be able to indicate that content should be written to a file doesn't mean they need to actually write it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list(or whatever data structure you like) that is accessible to parallel threads. Then add record to that list in each thread

```
 lock (yourList) {
    // here you can add items to the List
  }
```

When finished, dump your list to a file.
Or create a new List per each thread, return them all back, and then join all lists into one.
Or use a Database and add records to a table (the most logical solution)

As alternative solution

1. Create a global List
2. pass that list to all threads and lock it(example above) and write to it; unlock it
3. Create another infinite loop thread with delay
4. Inside infinite loop, after delay, lock the list, get all the data, write to file, empty the list
5. release the list